# Run example in Documentation not working in 10.2?

Tags: command-line

From `Run`'s documentation

```
 commandstring = First[$CommandLine] <> " -noprompt -run \"Put[Factorial[20],ToFileName[$TemporaryDirectory,ToString[temp1]]];Quit[]\""

(* "WolframKernel -noprompt -run "Put[Factorial[20],ToFileName[$TemporaryDirectory,ToString[temp1]]];Quit[]" *)
```

It is then claimed that this command exits without error

```
 Run[commandstring]

 (* 0 *)
```

but instead of the documented output -  `2432902008176640000`, no file seems to have been `Put`?

```
 FilePrint[ToFileName[$TemporaryDirectory, ToString[temp1]]]

 (* General::noopen: Cannot open /var/folders/1k/xb6km42x5fg7bv3g2hdnjft40000gn/T/temp1. >> *)
```

[Observed on Mma V 10.2 , OS X 10.10.5]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a documentation bug that has been fixed recently.

The following properly escaped for running in a shell version of the example should work on OS X,

```
commandstring = First[$CommandLine] <> 
  " -noprompt -run \"Put[Factorial[20], FileNameJoin[{\$TemporaryDirectory, \\\"temp1\\\"}]
]; Quit[]\""

Run[commandstring]

(* 0 *)

FilePrint[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "temp1"}]]

(* 2432902008176640000 *)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I could have I suppose, spotted that escaping on a shell first but still - am mildly curious as to whether or not documentation inputs are included in regression testing ...